# Normalizing test scores — public health inspections across diverse jurisdictions

Tags: normalization

I'm building a system to put the world's restaurant health scores online. I'm implementing [a data standard](http://www.yelp.com/healthscores) which only requires the scores to be 0–100, 100=maximum.

That was easy.

My current problem and question is, how to normalize the scores so that they're (1) meaningful to readers, and (2) informative comparing across regions.

**For context:** Every region in the U.S. does inspections differently. But they all follow USDA recommendations for kinds of violations and relative severities.

## A concrete example

A popular restaurant in Portland, Oregon got an 84/100. Very few restaurants in Portland score this low. Over half score above 98. 100's are common. However, in NYC, this isn't such a bad score. There, it's rare to see a 100.

I'm *mostly* concerned about informing a local visitor to the data: i.e., communicating that 84/100 is **bad** for a PDX restaurant. Secondarily, it'd be quite awesome if a normalized scale could fairly allow comparisons across jursidctions.

I'm not a statistics pro, and so my first guess is that converting a restaurant's score into a percentile for its region is the best way to normalize. Or even quartile, which neatly maps to *A, B, C, D*. But then I've got the problem that maybe Portland restaurants just *are cleaner* than those in NYC. (?!)

Are there standard practices, algorithms, or functions I should learn about?

Comment: No function or algorithm operating on scores alone is going to be able to help you tell whether NYC has stricter inspectors or dirtier restaurants than Portland, unless you've some instances of restaurants assessed by inspectors from both regions. You *could* try some kind of weighted average of regionally & nationally normalized scores - putting the regional average in brackets after the score might be more straightforward & less contentious.

Comment: @Scortchi Yep, after more research, I'm thinking that I simply can't present meaningful summary statistics. Instead, I could provide helpful context, e.g. display links to higher-scoring restaurants in the area.